# C/C++ testing framework (like JUnit for java)

Tags: c++, c, testing

Been hitting my head on the wall before as I don't make any test classes while using c/c++ (but instead have **a lot** of print methods).

What is the most used method to perform testing in the c/c++ code? Java's JUnit has only left me with good memories while debugging things.

I know that using asserts in code with a defined debug header should work, but aren't there any better ways?

And since I have the intention to make test classes in the future, any useful tips are welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check these out:

http://gamesfromwithin.com/?p=29

http://www.opensourcetesting.org/unit_c.php

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc136757.aspx

Comment: First link to gamesfromwithin has all I needed to know about different frameworks (at least for now). Thank you.

Comment: Keep in mind that the gamesfromwithin.com article, although excellent, was written in 2004, and things have changed since then.

Comment: For UnitTest++ go to github.com/unittest-cpp/unittest-cpp. Everything else is out of date.

Answer (score 15):

We use [Google Test](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) and it's companion [Google Mock](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/).  Works wonderfully and supports JUnit style XML output for easy integration with CruiseControl, etc.  It's also fully cross platform, and from my research a few months ago, GMock was the *ONLY* fully cross platform object mocking framework for C++.

Comment: Google Test and Google Mock are merged (since the answer is a bit outdated now). :)

Answer (score 13):

We use [boost.Test](http://www.boost.org/libs/test/).  There is also [cppunit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cppunit/).

Answer (score 3):

[UnitTest++](http://unittest-cpp.sourceforge.net/) is worth a look.  It lacks features compared to some of the other frameworks mentioned here, but the simplicity is nice -- especially if you're just getting started.

I believe it was developed by Noel Llopis after writing the article mentioned in http://gamesfromwithin.com/?p=29.  It is pretty easy to port to a multitude of different compilers/platforms -- useful if need to target something other than a PC, be it a game console, embedded device, or otherwise.

The mailinglist has been quiet for a while now, but every so often there are questions, patches, and/or a new release, and people who ask questions are usually answered quickly.

Comment: Seconded. I've tried a handful of unit test frameworks for C++, and UnitTest++ is easily the best in my opinion.

You are correct that it was developed by Noel Llopis. See http://gamesfromwithin.com/?p=51.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia has a long list of unit testing frameworks for [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C.2B.2B) and another list for [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C).

Answer (score 2):

I'm working with [Qt](http://www.trolltech.com) under Windows and Linux, wich provides an own integrated (but compared to other separate solutions a little bit limited) testing framework.

It's very easy to use and fast to learn - see [QTestLib](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qtestlib-manual.html)

ciao,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

Another problem people grossly over-engineer.

The below is a top-of-my-head, rough, non-working implementation of a nominal unit test infrastructure.  It makes some sense to construct Test with a `std::string` namespace/class name and use a consistent naming scheme to print out which test is failing.  I just use a unit test template and have some scripts that find all the executables starting with `u` (one per class), runs them in turn and collects the return values.

```
struct Test
{
   std::vector<(std::string)fptr*(void)> tests;
   int run() const
   {
      int stat(0);
      for (/* tests */)
      {
         std::string const res(test.run());
         if (!res.empty())
         {
             std::cerr << res;
             ++stat;
         }
      }
      return stat;
   }
};

std::string test1()
{
   std::ostringstream oss;
// do a bunch of stuff
// mark some of this code to be pulled into the class documentation 

   // conditional checks follow
   if (fail)
   {
      oss << "fail: some reason" << std::endl;
   }
// more checks
   return oss.str();
}

int main(void)
{
   Tests tests;
   tests.push_back(test1);
   tests.push_back(test2);
   return tests.run();
}
```

Comment: Well, yes. But a good unit testing framework really does a lot more than that.

Comment: Like couple all of your object files together and force you into pullling in yet another library?

Answer (score 1):

Shameless plug: If you target Windows and are using Visual Studio, check out [cfix](http://www.cfix-testing.org/) and [cfix studio](http://www.cfix-studio.com/).

It is also compatible to WinUnit.

Answer (score 1):

newest version of Visual Studio has something:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243147(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [CppUnit](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppunit/index.php?title=Main_Page)?  It was created as a port of JUnit.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows, take a look at: [Limitations of using C++/CLI with NUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243673/limitations-of-using-c-cli-with-nunit) and write your tests in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_Extensions_for_C%2B%2B.

also: http://golios.blogspot.com/2008/12/using-nunit-with-c-part-2.html, http://golios.blogspot.com/2008/11/using-nunit-with-native-c.html

this will work *just* like junit except for the fact that nunit does not create a new instance of the test case class before running each test.

Answer (score 0):

if it's for Windows platform you can try WinUnit from MS from here. [Simplified Unit Testing for Native C++ Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc136757.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For Symbian there is SymbianOSUnit: http://www.symbianosunit.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

Try using Catch. http://catch-lib.net

It's simple to use and setup and powerful enough for most.

Answer (score 0):

In 2019 :

- [Google's C++ test framework](https://github.com/google/googletest)
- GUnit
- Glib test