# C/C++ Testing framework

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, testing

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [C/C++ testing framework (like JUnit for java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067236/c-c-testing-framework-like-junit-for-java)
>   [C++ unit testing framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87794/c-unit-testing-framework)

Which of these is a better option to choose for developing an Automated Test Framework which should be platform independent (Windows/Linux/Mac) ?

1. CUnit
2. Check
3. Google test C++ Testing framework.

Or please feel free to suggest any other Testing Framework better than these satisfying the requirements.

Comment: Or suggest any other Testing Framework better than these satisfying the requirements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C/C++ testing framework (like JUnit for java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067236/c-c-testing-framework-like-junit-for-java), [C++ unit testing framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87794/c-unit-testing-framework) etc.

Comment: Check the SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699/choosing-a-c-unit-testing-tool-framework

Comment: For UnitTest++ go to github.com/unittest-cpp/unittest-cpp. Everything else is out of date.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using Boost.Test:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/test/doc/html/index.html

Comment: how about UnitTest++ or GoogleTest?

Answer (score 2):

1. [cxxtest](http://cxxtest.tigris.org/)
2. [cpptest](http://cpptest.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

CTest? It is part of [CMake](http://www.cmake.org).

Comment: CTest won't do it alone as it seems.

CTest is part of CMake which can be used as a cross platform build tool. It also includes CPack which one can use for cross platform installer generators. You can also integrate CTest with CDash, a software testing server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a unit testing framework? If yes, you should check out [CPPUnit](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppunit/index.php?title=Main_Page).

Comment: how about UnitTest++ or GoogleTest?