# UnitTesting for mixed C++/Cli projects

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++-cli

Which UnitTest framework should I use to test mixed C++ code (native and C++/CLI)? Any HowTo's or Tutorials?

Thx

Comment: Which unit test frameworks have you used before?

Comment: If you are using VS2012 you can add managed test projects for the C++ CLI projects and the native unit test C++ projects. Add | New Project | Visual C++...

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010627/unresolved-externals-when-compiling-unit-tests-for-visual-c-2012/17783030#17783030

Comment: Test it the same way it is going to be used by client code.  Which is pretty likely to be managed code for a C++/CLI library, so use a managed unit test runner.  If you want to test the native code then break it apart so you can get to the C++ code.  Putting it in a static library that gets linked in the C++/CLI project is boilerplate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use NUnit to test both very easily. If you write the tests in C++/CLI you will be able to test the native code too.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243673/limitations-of-using-c-cli-with-nunit) for a related discussion.